# Setting initial selected index based up view's tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to set the selected index of a UISegementControl based up on a views tag.

I have a special list of tags, that might change over time.

I run through a for loop to set the view's tag.

```
[[[self.segmentDuty subviews] objectAtIndex:i] setTag:someListofTags[i]];
```

That works fine as I can press the segment and get the correct tag.

```
NSInteger tagnumber =  [[self.segmentDuty.subviews objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]] tag];
```

The problem I having is setting the initial SELECTED index.

```
 for (UIView * view in self.segmentDuty.subviews){
        if(view.tag == someInitialTagNumber){

            ??? HERE is where I am having issue making the connection between index and tag
            //[self.segmentDuty  isSelected];

            break;
        }
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: Your code is correct, may be `someInitialTagNumber ` not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you set the selectedIndex, how about do it this way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.segmentDuty.subviews count]; i++) {
    UIView* view = [self.segmentDuty.subviews objectAtIndex: i];
    if(view.tag == someInitialTagNumber){

            self.segmentDuty. selectedSegmentIndex = i;
            break;
    }
}
```